# Difference between File.renameTo and Files.move: Which is faster?

Tags: java

Both `File.renameTo` and `Files.move` in Java can move a file. What's the difference between the two? And which has a better performance?

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation before posting a question? [`renameTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29), [`move`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29). It looks like you haven't, so you're going to get answers that are lifted directly from this documentation.

Comment: Offtopic-  Files is only in JDK7.   Apache common's FileUtils helped us  lot.

Comment: The difference in performance is most likely not important (unless you need to delete thousands of files and there is some reason why this is perfomance-critical).

Answer (score 10):

```
public boolean renameTo(File dest)
```

> Renames the file denoted by this abstract pathname.
>
> Many aspects of
>   the behavior of this method are inherently **platform-dependent**: The
>   rename operation might not be able to move a file from one file system
>   to another and it might not succeed if a file with the destination
>   abstract pathname already exists.
>
> [Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29)

But the `move` method can move or rename a file in a **platform independent** manner.

`renameTo` is just returning a **boolean** type but the `move` returns **the path to the target file**